# Ansible role dependency to specific task of another role

Tags: ansible

I am wondering if it is possible to specifiy the dependencies of one role to spedific tasks of other roles?

I know that it is possible to define role-dependencies in *rolename/meta/main.yml* like this

```
dependencies:
- { role: anotherrolename }
```

But if I want the role to be dependent to a specific task of *anotherrolename* I do not know how to specify it in meta/main.yml.

Of course one working solution is to use import role inside of the task like this at the beginning of my task:

```
- import_role:
  name: anotherrolename
  tasks_from: specifictaskname
```

But I think it would be a cleaner way to define all my dependencies in the meta/main.yml file. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible Roles are supposed to be monolithic. You can use tags to use subsections, but referring to individual tasks to fulfill a requirement to another role would defeat the purpose of roles.